# Luggage transfer from JFK to Newark

Tags: luggage

I have a 10 hour stop-over in New York with an airport change from JFK to Newark, will I have to carry my luggage or is there a book-through to destination option?

Comment: Yes. You are responsible to get yourself and your luggage to Newark.

Comment: Thank you! Found a luggage store on Penn Station that will store bags for the morning, Am going to explore the METT museum a bit.

Answer (score 4):

You will be required to pick up your luggage, transport it on your own, and check it in again on the other airport.

Because of this cumbersome process, such connections are typically sold cheaper.